# Python: required kwarg, which exception to raise?

Tags: python, exception

One way to ensure that a method is called with a particular kwarg would be like:

```
def mymethod(self, *args, **kwargs):
    assert "required_field" in kwargs
```

Raising an `AssertionError` doesn't seem like the most appropriate thing to do. Is there an agreed upon builtin exception to handle this with a nice error message?

More info: there are 3rd-party subclassing issues where *args and **kwargs kinda' need to be passed so making "required_field" a positional argument is not really a good option.

Comment: I think the standard thing is to not make it a 'default argument'.

Comment: there are already positional arguments that I don't want to mess with.

Comment: More generally, there are also cases were kwargs can may accept numerous keys with some being required only if specific conditions are met with respect to the presence or values of other key word arguments.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
>>> def foo(bar): pass
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bar'
```

I'd just go with TypeError..

Answer (score 32):

+1 for TypeError. This is what Python 3 raises for required keyword-only arguments:

```
>>> def foo(*, x):
...     pass
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() needs keyword-only argument x
>>> foo(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 0 positional arguments (1 given)
>>> foo(x=2)
```

*(TypeError suggestion was already given (and accepted); I wrote this answer to mention this Python 3 feature).*

Comment: Mentioning the Python 3 keyword-only arguments is extremely helpful here; people might be coming to this question thinking they should do the exception handling themselves when the language itself supports required keyword arguments (unless they are unfortunate enough to be stuck with Python 2, of course).

Comment: I ended up here googling for the syntax of required kwargs, so +1 from me as well.

Answer (score 18):

The standard library seems to like to raise `TypeError` when it gets the wrong number of arguments.  That's essentially your problem, so I'd raise that.

That said, `**kwargs` essentially fill in for default arguments most of the time, so having a required default argument seems a little surprising/confusing.

Note that python will happily let you call positional arguments by keyword:

```
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     print a, b
... 
>>> foo(a=1, b=2)
1 2
>>> foo(b=1, a=2)
2 1
```

but I suppose that then they *all* have to be referenced by keyword (`foo(2, a=2)` doesn't work) which you may not want.

Comment: "`**kwargs` is essentially fill in for default arguments most of the time". Not really. That's one use, but `**kwargs` has several other important uses: 1) in superclasses where subclasses may want different behavior, 2) when you have a long argument list where you don't want the client to have to memorize the order of the arguments `**kwargs` avoids a lot of clutter. There are no doubt others, but those are the first ones that come to mind. The former (superclass) was what ended up leading me to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think `KeyError` would be the most appropriate, because `**kwargs` is a `dict`.

```
>>> def foo(**kwargs):
...  print kwargs['abc']
...
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
KeyError: 'abc'
```

If the field is actually required, you could check for it

```
try:
  kwargs['required']
except KeyError:
  raise KeyError('required is a Required Argument')
```

Comment: `KeyError` usually applies directly to a data structure, whereas the OP wants to notify a misuse of the function signature.

Answer (score -2):

If you need it to be a required keyword, do something like:

```
def mymethod(self,myrequired=None):
    if myrequired==None:
        #raise error
    #do other stuff down here
```

You shouldnt really need to pull it from kwargs.

Comment: just add `*args,**kwargs` :)